# How to get the data from database and parse data into the fopen function

Tags: php

Am getting the filepath from the database.I stored the filepath into a variable but when am attempting to parse that variable into the fopen function,it throws an error says, filename cannot be empty.

login.html

```
<form action="a.php" method="POST">
Username: <input type="text" name="username"></br>
Password: <input type="text" name="password"></br>
Email-Address: <input type="text" name="email_address"></br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

a.php

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","abc","abc","mysql");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$username= $_POST['username'];
$password= $_POST['password'];
$email=   $_POST['email_address'];
$r= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Assignment where email_address='$email'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
$filename = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $row['home_directory']);

if(isset($_POST['text1'])){
$file_open = fopen($filename,"w+"); 
fwrite($file_open, $_POST['text1']);
fclose($file_open);
}
?>

<form action="" method="POST">
<textarea  class="text_edit" name="text1"  id="my_text" ></textarea></br>

<input type="submit" name="button">
    </form>
```

I coudnt to find out whats the mistake here.why the fopen doesn't work with the retreived filepath from the database

Comment: Does your login.html call to a.php & then again a.php calls itself?

Comment: No, login.html calls a.php only one time. In a.php,another submit button is there after I pressed that submit button,$filename becomes empty.

Comment: Is problem because of two submit buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Check if $filename is empty or not with var_dump function. Try this code :

```
$filename = $row['home_directory'];
var_dump($filename);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. using `var_dump($filename)`,outputs string(11) "article.txt". But still throws an error that filename cannot be empty after the submit button is pressed. And `var_dump($filename)`shows a output as null after the submit button is pressed.

Comment: problem is,after submit button is pressed,$filename becomes empty so that fopen function doesnot work

Comment: Check your SQL request.

Comment: I could get the filepath from the database that is confirmed by doing `echo $filename`.It outputs the filename but if $filename is inside the fopen(),it doesn't work..

Comment: Are you trying to write data when form of a.php is being submitted ?

Comment: hm yes.In textarea the $filename will be opened. After the changes have made into the textarea it should be saved back to the $filename by submit button. But here, after the submit button is pressed the $filename becomes empty

Comment: I could open and read the $filename into textarea but after some changes of the content,if I hit submit button,throws an error $filename cannot be empty rather than changes of the content is saved back to the file